# Formik Invalid value for prop `value` on <input> tag

Tags: reactjs, next.js, formik

I'm building a form using [Formik](https://formik.org/) library on a **NextJS** project (*Typescript*), but when I render my form I get some warnings on the browser that say:

```
Warning: Invalid value for prop `value` on <input> tag. Either remove it from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the DOM.
```

[image]

That's how I render my fields

```js
<FormGroup>
 <InputGroup>
  <InputLabel>
    {t('flightsCheckout.main.firstName')}
  </InputLabel>
  <Field name={`passengers[${index}].firstName`}>
    {({field}) => (
      <TextInput {...field} required
        placeholder="E.G. John (Given Name)" type="text"/>
    )}
  </Field>
 </InputGroup>
 <DottedLinesContainer>
  <DottedLines />
 </DottedLinesContainer>
 <InputGroup>
  <InputLabel>
    {t('flightsCheckout.main.lastName')}
  </InputLabel>
  <Field name={`passengers[${index}].lastName`}>
   {({ field }) => (
    <TextInput {...field} required placeholder="E.G. Smith (Last Name)" type="text"/>
   )}
  </Field>
 </InputGroup>
</FormGroup>
```

how can I clear these warnings ?

Comment: What does `<TextInput {...field}`, `...field` result to?

Comment: @AseemGautam {...field} has { name, value, onChange, onBlur }

Comment: @AseemGautam https://formik.org/docs/api/field

Comment: What is the value of `value`  field?

Comment: @AseemGautam it actually has no value
E.G : 
<input name="passengers[0].firstName" required="" placeholder="E.G. John (Given Name)" type="text" class="styled__TextInput-sc-826f1c7c-56 cLFvus" value="">

Comment: Which is normal for an initial value

Comment: But if you log `field.value` to the console, what's its actual value? The actual value matters here. If it's `undefined` it may cause the error you're seeing, so you may want to default it to an empty string instead.

Comment: @juliomalves so it's  better to {...field, {value: ""}}

Comment: That will overwrite it to empty string, not default it to that value. You want to set it to empty string only if it's `undefined`.

Comment: @juliomalves initial value is empty string `console.log(field)`
`{
    "name": "passengers[3].firstName",
    "value": ""
}`